# Cant able to drag set of elements

Tags: svg, raphael

I am creating two elements (1. arrow shape and 2. dotted line) using path (Raphael and SVG) and I want to drag these two together but I am only able to drag it independently. Here is my code for this:

```
 gaugeSvg = Raphael("gauge");

 $(document).ready( function () {
            redraw();
       });

 function redraw() {

        //Add a Arrow and line
        var rect = gaugeSvg.path('M 0 0 L 40 -34 L 40 -14 L 80 -14 L 80 14 L 40 14 L 40 34 Z');

        rect.attr({
        "stroke": "black",
        "fill" : "black",
        "enable" : "true",
        }).translate(left + width, goalY);

        var txt =  gaugeSvg.path('M 0 0 L ' + width + " 0");

        txt.attr({
        "stroke": "black",
        "stroke-width": 12,
        "stroke-dasharray": "-",
        "stroke-linecap": "round"
        }).translate(left, goalY);

        //Create a set so we can move the
       //arrow and line at the same time
       var g = gaugeSvg.set();
       g.push(rect, txt);
      // var g = gaugeSvg.set(rect, txt);

       var me = this,
       lx = 0,
       ly = 0,
       ox = 0,
       oy = 0,
       moveFnc = function(dx, dy) {
           this.translate(dx-ox, dy-oy);
           ox = dx;
           oy = dy;  
       },
       startFnc = function() {},
       endFnc = function() {
           ox = lx;
           oy = ly;
       };

        g.drag(moveFnc, startFnc, endFnc);
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have'nt used Rapheal . But i have achieved this Drag functionlaity with SVG amd Javascript.

In order to move multiple elements, you need to group them. Means put these elements in 'g' group and then apply drag function on this 'g'. and once finished, you need to 'ungroup' them.

you can see demo here http://jsfiddle.net/rehankhalid/5t5pX/

```
var mainsvg = document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];

 function mousemove(event) {
        var svgXY = getSvgCordinates(event);// get current x,y w.r.t to your svg.
        dx = svgXY.x - mx;// mx means x cordinates of mouse down
        dy = svgXY.y - my;

        draggroup.setAttribute('transform', 'translate(' + dx + ',' + dy + ')');

    }

function getSvgCordinates(event) {
            var m = mainsvg.getScreenCTM();
            var p = mainsvg.createSVGPoint();
            var x, y;

            x = event.pageX;
            y = event.pageY;

            p.x = x;
            p.y = y;
            p = p.matrixTransform(m.inverse());

            x = p.x;
            y = p.y;

            x = parseFloat(x.toFixed(3));
            y = parseFloat(y.toFixed(3));

            return {x: x, y: y};
        }
```